# Can we add a "Low Quality" reason to the close vote?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

Maybe it's just me, but I seem to be seeing a lot more very low-quality posts than before. Some, like this one, seem almost unsalvageable (especially pre-edit):  [Object Merge ShortCut](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53199/object-merge-shortcut)

EDIT: This is an even better example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53213/make-human-import-intro-blender-and-export-blend-animation-to-three-js

Even editing the question would have to involve a number of assumptions about what the OP is even trying to ask.

I don't want to discourage people from participating, but I DO want to discourage them from blurting out the first set of words that comes to mind and putting a question-mark at the end of it. There should be a good close reason for posts that just can't be improved by anyone but the OP.

But, there's no "Low Quality" close reason. I'm thinking of one like on SuperUser:

- Very low quality

  This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Comment: Turns out... this is a "flag reason" that I somehow overlooked. Why would we have such a reason for a flag, but not close?

Comment: "blurting out the first set of words that comes to mind and putting a question-mark at the end of it." This actually describes remarkably well what a lot of questions appear like.

Comment: I suspect that the site has become large enough to be found by people with Blender questions (YAY!!) But that's attracting lots of askers who seem to be unfamiliar with SE, and most of them don't pick up on the clues that there's more research to be done about how to use this site, than there would be with any other new-found forum. (I can sympathize with the thought process that just doesn't notice how different SE is, and it just doesn't trigger that they need to figure out how to use it differently from any other forum on the web).

Comment: In the past we've used "unclear what your asking" for this. It seems pretty applicable to the two questions you linked, imo.

Comment: That's sounds more reasonable than adding a new reason. Care to make that an answer? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the existing "unclear what you're asking" close reason covers this pretty well already.

I also think it's less likely to come across as "your question is bad", something which "low quality" could quite easily do.